# What is the difference between .word and .equ in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips

I think both do about the same: Variable declaration and initialization. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.word` allocates space and initializes the data. `.equ` defines a constant, but doesn't allocate any space for it.

So, for example, you might say:

```
one .equ 1  ; defines a constant called "one"
counter: .word one ; allocates space and initializes it with the value 1
```

The difference being that the `.equ` directive doesn't allocate any space in the compiled image.

Comment: As an analogy to C, your first line is like `#define one 1`, and your second line is like `word counter = one;`